# laravel 5.3 Authentication User Provider Issue

Tags: laravel

I am working on laravel 5.3. Here i have used

```
if(Auth::attempt(['username'=>$username,'password'=>$password]))
```

but showing error that `Authentication user provider [] is not defined in larval 5.3`.I did's get this error in laravel 5.2

Comment: Did you check for a solution on stackoverflow before? What all did you tried to do, to solve this? Explain more, so we can give you can answer. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188003/laravel-multi-auth-authentication-user-provider-is-not-defined This was posted 2 days ago....

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
php artisan make:provider MerchantServiceProvider
```

and use this in app/config.php section provider :

```
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class ,
```

Comment: it's not working.still getting Authentication user provider [] is not defined error. i have run php artisan make:provider MerchantServiceProvider and configured in app/config.php but still getting that error

Comment: use `composer dump-autoload` and still see .

Comment: it's done.actually i missed some code in auth. but i got it thankyou

Comment: your welcome  , you see link https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar